# Работа со строками и файлами

Tags: java

Как в стек записать строки и вывести их в файл в обратном порядке на java?

Comment: А не проще в новый файл их закинуть?

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] arr// ваш массив строк полученный ранее
...
try(BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename"))) {
    for(int i=arr.length-1;i>-1;i--){
        writer.write(arr[i]);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Вместо массива можно использовать коллекцию, изменения кода будут минимальны

этот вариант читает из файла filename1 и пишет в файл filename2

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename1"))) {
        String buf;
        while ((buf = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            strings.add(buf);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename2"))) {
        for (int i = strings.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            writer.write(strings.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```